# Expected unqualified-id in typename T::type::value

Tags: c++, c++14

Consider the following code:

```
template <class T>
bool value = typename T::type::value;
```

Where `type` is a member type of `T` and `value` should be a static data member of `type`.

I compiled with `clang++-6.0 -std=c++14` and it emitted:

```
a.cc:2:37: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
bool value = typename T::type::value;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

How to correct this?

Comment: You can't initialize a `bool`  variable with a type as indicated by `bool value = typename ...`. It must instead be some expression/variable/function return value that is at least convertible to `bool`.

Comment: I guess it should work if you remove the `typename` (assuming `T` provides `type` which provides a `value` and `value` is compatible to `bool`).

Comment: This is similar to saying `bool value = bool;` The compiler thinks you're missing something from trying to do a cast like - `bool value = bool(1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix:

```
template <class T>
bool constexpr value = T::type::value;
```

You are accessing a value here, so `typename` is not needed.

Scope resolution operator `::` in `T::type::` implies that `type` can only be a type, no ambiguity there, hence `typename` is unnecessary.

Comment: @ Maxim Egorushkin Thanks, can you tell me why? I was told that whenever I tried to use a member type, I should add ```typename```before it.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu You are accessing a value here, so `typename` is not needed. Scope resolution operator `::` in `X::` implies that `X` can only be a type, no ambiguity there.

Comment: Got the trick with the `constexpr` - thanks. Though, there isn't a `constexpr` in OP's sample code...